# WARNING: Sentinel was not able to save the new configuration on disk!!!: Device or resource busy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, docker-machine, redis-sentinel

I am trying to setup one master one slave and one sentinel on docker, for that I wrote this docker compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-master:
    container_name: "redis-master"
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: "redis-server /etc/redis.conf"
    volumes:
      - "./data/master:/data/"
      - "./master.conf:/etc/redis.conf"

  redis-slave:
    container_name: "redis-slave"
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    command: "redis-server /etc/redis.conf"
    volumes:
      - "./data/slave:/data/"
      - "./slave.conf:/etc/redis.conf"
    depends_on:
      - redis-master

  redis-sentinel:
    container_name: 'redis-sentinel'
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "26379:26379"
    command: >
      bash -c "chmod 777 /etc/sentinel.conf
      && redis-server /etc/sentinel.conf --sentinel"
    volumes:
      - "./sentinel.conf:/etc/sentinel.conf"
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
      - redis-slave
```

But when I try to build it using `sudo docker-compose up --build --force` all the services are runnning fine except the redis-sentinel. I got this error in logs

```
redis-sentinel    | 1:X 16 Dec 2021 19:15:21.486 # +sdown master mymaster 172.23.0.2 6379
redis-sentinel    | 1:X 16 Dec 2021 19:15:21.486 # +odown master mymaster 172.23.0.2 6379 #quorum 1/1
redis-sentinel    | 1:X 16 Dec 2021 19:15:21.486 # +new-epoch 8
redis-sentinel    | 1:X 16 Dec 2021 19:15:21.487 # +try-failover master mymaster 172.23.0.2 6379
redis-sentinel    | 1:X 16 Dec 2021 19:15:22.955 # Could not rename tmp config file (Device or resource busy)
redis-sentinel    | 1:X 16 Dec 2021 19:15:22.955 # WARNING: Sentinel was not able to save the new configuration on disk!!!: Device or resource busy
```

I understand this is some file permission and I have to make sentinel.conf executable but I am not able to think of any possible solutions in docker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the sentinel command should be only like this (we will sort out the permissions later):

```
redis-server /etc/sentinel.conf --sentinel
```

In order to resolve that warning, you have to do the following (for all the redis nodes - master, slave, sentinel):

In the folder where the docker-compose.yml resides, create a "config" folder, with the following structure:

```
/config
  /redis-master
     redis.conf
  /redis-slave
     redis.conf
  /redis-sentinel
     redis.conf
```

Inside config/redis-master folder you copy your current **master.conf** file as **redis.conf** (for the sake of simplicity).

Inside config/redis-slave you copy your current **slave.conf** file as **redis.conf**

Inside config/redis-sentinel you will copy your current **sentinel.conf** as **redis.conf**

Then, execute this command, in order to give full rights to all the content of your "config" folder:

```
chmod -R 0777 config/
```

Now, change your service definitions in the docker-compose, like this:
(notice my changes in the "command" and "volumes" sections)

```
  redis-master:
    container_name: "redis-master"
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: "redis-server /etc/redis-config/redis.conf"
    volumes:
      - "./data/master:/data/"
      - "./config/redis-master:/etc/redis-config"
```

```
  redis-slave:
    container_name: "redis-slave"
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    command: "redis-server /etc/redis-config/redis.conf"
    volumes:
      - "./data/slave:/data/"
      - "./config/redis-slave:/etc/redis-config"
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
```

```
  redis-sentinel:
    container_name: 'redis-sentinel'
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "26379:26379"
    command: "redis-server /etc/redis-config/redis.conf --sentinel"
    volumes:
      - "./config/redis-sentinel:/etc/redis-config"
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
      - redis-slave
```

Conclusions:

1. In order for redis to have rights to modify the configurations, you have mount the entire configuration folder, not the file itself (and the folder contents should be writable).
2. Back-up all the original master.conf, slave.conf, sentinel.conf files. Be aware that redis will alter your local configuration files (redis.conf), because eventually you will execute failovers, so the slave config will be turned into a master one and the opposite for the master config. It's up to you how you avoid committing the changes to source control. For example, you can keep the originals in a separate folder, and copy them to the mounted folder by a deploy script, before running "docker-compose up" command.
3. All the changes that redis will apply to these config files will be appended at the end of the config and will be preceded by this comment:

```
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
```

This solution is tested by me and it works. I came out with this solution after reading @yossigo 's answer regarding a similar warning:

https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/8172

Comment: This does work. I also have 'Could not rename tmp config file (Device or resource busy)' in my log, and after retry with this attempt, it works.